# Integral of regions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Consider the region $$E = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1,\; z\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\}$$
How we can draw the region?

How to compute integral limits for $\int_E \frac{z\,x^2}{x^2+y^2}\, dx\,dy\,dz$ ?

Comment: Show your efforts! Gimusi suggests the use of cylindrical or spherical coordinates. Write your attempt under the question .

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

To figure out the region try to consider simple plot on $x-z$, $y-z$ and $x-y$ planes. You should easily find that

- the region $x^2 +y^2 +z^2 \le1$  is the interior of a sphere with
  radius 1 centered at the origin
- the surface $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is a cone on $z>0$ side with vertex in the origin and $z\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$  is
  the region under the cone

To compute the integral a good choice is to use [spherical
    coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) with

- $x=r\sin\phi\cos\theta$
- $y=r\sin\phi\sin\theta$
- $z=r\cos\phi$

and with the limits

- $0\le \theta \le 2\pi$
- $0\le r \le 1$
- $-\frac{\pi}2\le \phi \le \frac{\pi}4$

Remember also that in this case

$$dx\,dy\,dz=r^2\sin \phi \,d\phi \,d\theta \,dr$$

[image]

Comment: can you provide me only the integration limits?

Comment: @TayyabIlyas I have update the hint, spherical coordinates should be better

Comment: @TayyabIlyas You only need to vizualize the region, $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1$ is the interior of a sphere with radius 1 centered at the origin, $z= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is a cone and $z\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the region under the cone. Thus the region is a sphere less a cone on top.

Comment: I agree with these.

Comment: @TayyabIlyas I've added now all the ingredients, if you agree with the set up let try to solve and show your work, I will be happy to check it!

Comment: thanks. and how to transform the  function $\int_E \frac{z\,x^2}{x^2+y^2}\, dx\,dy\,dz$ ?

Comment: $-\frac{\pi}2\le \phi \le \frac{\pi}4\pi $ or $-\frac{\pi}2\le \phi \le \frac{\pi}4$?

Comment: @TayyabIlyas just plug in the value for x,y,z in spherical coordinates and the for the dxdydz term, then integrate!

Comment: @TayyabIlyas ops it was just a typo, of course $$-\frac{\pi}2\le \phi \le \frac{\pi}4$$